# How can I squash commits between A and K into one commit Z

Tags: git, squash

If I have a commit history like this:

```
A-B-C-------G-H-J-K   (master)
     \     /
      D-E-F
```

how can I squash commits between A and K into one commit Z:

```
A-Z-K   (master)
```

?

Comment: Useful link - [Combining multiple commits into one using git rebase](http://feeding.cloud.geek.nz/posts/combining-multiple-commits-into-one/)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, execute:

```
git rebase -i A
```

This will show a list of commits in a text editor, starting with B and ending with K.
You will have to change the text `pick` in front of commits C, D, E, F, H and J to `s` or `squash`. Do *not* change `pick` in front of B or K. Please note that the commit G should be missing, because it is a merge commit.

Finally, save and exit the editor. This will start the actual rebasing.

The result will be this:

```
A-Z-K'                   (master)
 \
  B-C-------G-H-J-K      (no branch)
     \     /
      D-E-F
```

The part that is on no branch will eventually be removed by a garbage collection.

Comment: 1. What I have to do with commit B (live pick or change to squash)? 2. Is a rebase prosess replacing squashed commits or not?