# Forget commit history while sending pull request

Tags: git, github, git-rebase

I have a pull request to be sent on GitHub. The problem is that pull request is showing the history of all commits rather than the consolidated final change.
How do we achieve this? I am not an expert in rebasing,
Any help much appreciated

Comment: Can you provide a bit more detail?  How many commits do you expect to be included in the pull request?  Just the final one?

Comment: yes, consolidate all my changes to one  and then send the pull request

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I squash commits between A and K into one commit Z](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14850486/how-can-i-squash-commits-between-a-and-k-into-one-commit-z)

Answer (score 0):

You most likely want to perform an interactive rebase, squashing any commits that you do not want to make public.
See [this chapter](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Tools-Rewriting-History) in the Pro Git book.

Answer (score 0):

On GitHub pull requests works only on entire branches. If you only want to submit one commit you need to place it on a branch of its own.

Create a new branch from where you want your commit to be.
Then use `git cherry-pick` to get the commit you want to push.